# Struggling to parse (bash) time command

Tags: bash, time

I'm struggling to parse the output of the time command in bash - and even to stop it from printing out its output when I call it. This is my test code:

```
#!/bin/bash
TIME=`time ls -lh > /dev/null`
echo "Testing..."
echo $TIME
```

This currently prints out:

```
{blank-line}
real    0m0.064s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.005s
Testing
{blank-line}
```

So, it seems like the value assigned to `$TIME` is the blank line at the start of the time print-out. I need to get at the seconds value of the sys line - that is, the "0.005". I am guaranteed that I will only ever have seconds, so I do not need anything before the "m" - however, the seconds part may be in the form of xx.xxx if it goes >= 10 seconds. I currently have no idea how to suppress the 'time' output, capture it all instead of the blank line, nor parse it to get the values I need.

Any help would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you use the Bash builtin `time`, you can control its output by setting the `TIMEFORMAT` variable:

```
TIMEFORMAT=%R
```

and you won't have to do any parsing since that will cause `time` to only output the number of seconds.

and use this:

```
echo "Testing..."
TIME=$( { time ls -lh > /dev/null; } 2>&1 )
echo $TIME
```

or one of the other techniques from [BashFAQ/032](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032).

Answer (score 8):

First and foremost, the data you're trying to capture is being written to standard error. But capturing that output is fairly tricky in this case.

`time` is both an executable (in `/usr/bin`) as well as built-in shell command in bash and other shells. When you execute `time` without specifying `/usr/bin/time`, you are executing a built-in command in bash. This makes it hard to do things with the output, since bash does not treat it like a normal program; it's a special built-in function written by bash.

Knowing that, and looking at the man page for `time(1)`, I can see that the data you're trying to capture from `time` is outputted to stderr. So my workaround for this is to directly execute `/usr/bin/time` as follows:

```
TIME=`/usr/bin/time ls -lh 2>&1 >/dev/null`
```

This copies the standard error stream to standard out, and then redirects what normally goes to standard out to `/dev/null`. Standard error, however, will still go to standard out since it was duplicated before the redirection. Reversing the order of these will not work. (Yes, this is confusing.)

Unfortunately, `/usr/bin/time` is a bit less precise in its output:

```
    0.00 real         0.00 user         0.00 sys
```

---

Alternatively, you can use 2 sub-shells, as follows:

```
TIME=$((time ls -lh >/dev/null) 2>&1)
```

This would re-write what is written to standard error on the second subshell within the first, allowing you to capture the output. See http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html for more on sub-shells.

Comment: Or use only one sub-shell as `TIME="$( { time ls -lh >/dev/null; } 2>&1)`

Answer (score 2):

Although Solutions hover around the same logic, but still I couldn't find following listed, so another version of the solution:

```
TIME=$(time (ls -lh >/dev/null) 2>&1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `time` command outputs the timing information to STDERR, which you aren't capturing or redirecting.  So at the *time of the assignment*, that information is printed out to your console, while the `$TIME` variable gets the STDOUT of the command - which you redirected to `/dev/null`, so it's blank.

Perhaps you should try to capture the STDERR of the command?

Comment: Ah, I did not realise that time output to `STDERR`. How do I capture that in to the `$TIME` variable then?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post this as a comment, but it would be too long. I wanted to present another slightly different way to obtain the data.

You can use the two sub-shells to get the output of time as a stream using `/bin/sh` rather than `/usr/bin/time` to obtain the timing of the execution. I imagine you can substitute `time` here with `/usr/bin/time`.

```
$ ((time ./print_test.sh > deleteme) 2>&1) > deletemetime

$ cat deleteme
test

$ cat deletemetime
./print_test.sh > deleteme  0.00s user 0.00s system 86% cpu 0.003 total

$ ((time ./print_test.sh > deleteme) 2>&1) | sed 's/system/kernel/'
./print_test.sh > deleteme  0.00s user 0.00s kernel 86% cpu 0.003 total
```

Note also that there appears to be a difference in the way it will produce output. Sometimes it is in that format and sometimes it is in this format:

```
real    0m0.420s
user    0m0.385s
sys     0m0.040s
```

Not sure at this point what determines one way or the other.

Of course, you can use e.g.

```
TIMEFORMAT='%3R'
```

to fix the format.