# bash script write executing time in a file

Tags: bash

I need to write the time taken to execute this command in a txt file:

```
time ./program.exe
```

How can I do in bash script?

I try with `>> time.txt` but that doesn't work (the output does not go to file and does go to the screen).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Struggling to parse (bash) time command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928430/struggling-to-parse-bash-time-command)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Getting `time` in `bash` to write to a file is hard work.  It is a `bash` built-in command.  (On Mac OS X, there's an external command, `/usr/bin/time`, that does a similar job but with a different output format and less recalcitrance.)

You need to use:

```
(time ./program.exe) 2> time.txt
```

It writes to standard error (hence the `2>` notation).  However, if you don't use the sub-shell (the parentheses), it doesn't work; the output still comes to the screen.

---

Alternatively, and without a sub-shell, you can use:

```
{ time ./program.exe; } 2> time.txt
```

Note the space after the open brace and the semi-colon; both are necessary on a single line.  The braces must appear where a command could appear, and must be standalone symbols.  (If you struggle hard enough, you'll come up with `...;}|something` or `...;}2>&1`.  Both of these identify the brace as a standalone symbol, though. If you try `...;}xyz`, the shell will (probably) fail to find a command called `}xyz`, though.)

---

> I need to run more command in more terminal. If I do this:
>
> ```
>  xterm -xrm '*hold: true' -e (time ./Program.exe) >> time.exe & sleep 2
> ```
>
> it doesn't work and tells me `Syntax error: "(" unexpected`.  How do I fix this?

You would need to do something like:

```
xterm -xrm '*hold: true' -e sh -c "(time ./Program.exe) 2> time.txt & sleep 2"
```

The key change is to run the shell with the script coming from the argument to the `-c` option; you can replace `sh` with `/bin/bash` or an equivalent name.  That should get around any 'Syntax error' issues.  I'm not quite sure what triggers that error, though, so there may be a simpler and better way to deal with it.  It's also conceivable that `xterm`'s `-e` option only takes a single string argument, in which case, I suppose you'd use:

```
xterm -xrm '*hold: true' -e 'sh -c "(time ./Program.exe) 2> time.txt & sleep 2"'
```

You can manual bash `xterm` as well as I can.

I'm not sure why you run the timed program in background mode, but that's your problem, not mine.  Similarly, the `sleep 2` is not obviously necessary if the `hold: true` keeps the terminal open.

Comment: I need to run more command in more terminal. If i do this 
xterm -xrm '*hold: true' -e (time ./Program.exe) 2> time.exe &   
sleep 2

dont work and tell me Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Answer (score 1):

time_elapsed=`(time sh -c "./program.exe") 2>&1 | grep "real" | awk '{print $(NF)}'`
echo time_elapsed > file.txt
This command should give you the exact time consumed in bash in a desired file..

You can also redirect this to a file usng 2 > file.txt as explained in another reply.

Comment: Use TIMEFORMAT to control bash built-in time output (no need for `grep` + `awk` then).

Comment: So in this case: TIMEFORMAT=%lR; { time sh -c "./program.exe";} 2>file.txt

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to redirect the output of the bash builtin `time`.

One solution is to use the external `time` program:

```
/bin/time --append -o time.txt ./program.exe
```

(on most systems it's a GNU program, so use `info time` rather than `man` to get its documentation).

Comment: Note: this doesn't work with bash functions. The argument to GNU `time` must be a command available in your path.

Answer (score 0):

Just enclose the command to time in a `{ .. }`:

```
{ time ./program.exe; } 2>&1
```

Of course, the output of builtin time goes to stderr, thus the needed redirection `2>&1`.

Then, it may appear to be tricky to capture the output, let's use a second `{ .. }` to read the command more easily, this works:

```
{ { time ./program.exe; } 2>&1; } >> time.txt              # This works.
```

However, the correct construct should simply have the capture reversed, as this:

```
{ time ./program.exe; } >> time.txt  2>&1;                 # Correct.
```

To close any possible output from the command, redirect it's output to /dev/null, as this:

```
{ time ./program.exe >/dev/null 2>&1; } >> time.txt 2>&1   # Better.
```

And, as now there is only output on stderr, we could simply capture just it:

```
{ time ./program.exe >/dev/null 2>&1; } 2>> time.txt       # Best.
```

The output from ./program should be redirected, or it may well end inside time.txt.