# How to redirect the output of the time command to a file in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, time

Just a little question about timing programs on Linux: the time command allows to
measure the execution time of a program:

```
[ed@lbox200 ~]$ time sleep 1

real    0m1.004s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.004s
```

Which works fine. But if I try to redirect the output to a file, it fails.

```
[ed@lbox200 ~]$ time sleep 1 > time.txt

real    0m1.004s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.004s

[ed@lbox200 ~]$ cat time.txt 
[ed@lbox200 ~]$
```

I know there are other implementations of time with the option -o to write a file but
my question is about the command without those options.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bash script write executing time in a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176611/bash-script-write-executing-time-in-a-file), and I'm far from convinced that this is the first such question.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408981/how-can-i-redirect-the-output-of-the-time-command

Answer (score 375, accepted):

Try

```
{ time sleep 1 ; } 2> time.txt
```

which combines the STDERR of "time" and your command into time.txt

Or use

```
{ time sleep 1 2> sleep.stderr ; } 2> time.txt
```

which puts STDERR from "sleep" into the file "sleep.stderr" and only STDERR from "time" goes into "time.txt"

Comment: Thanks, that answers precisely my question. If I correctly understood, the time command's result can be obtained from stderr?

Comment: Yes, but you must put it in curly brackets, otherwise the redirection will be part of the command that `time` evaluates.

Comment: Not a valid answer, even with the curly brackets update.  Using a command which generates error output will show that in the above syntax time.txt will contain the command's error and time's output.  It seems the original question is asking how to capture time output independently from _any_ command output.  A problem I have not yet solved.

Comment: @Daniel You could always redirect the internal command output separately (i.e. { time sleep 1 2> sleepStdErr.txt ; } 2> time.txt ) and that would get you only the time output. I'm not sure if there's a way to get it independently otherwise.

Comment: @gms7777 Thanks.  I can grep/cat the output files as needed so that syntax splits them up for my needs.

Comment: If you want to use time with something like grep that reads off of stdout try `{ time sleep 1; } 2>&1 | grep real`. This sends stderr to stdout which grep can then read.

Comment: do NOT forget the ';' character before closing '}' , it will NOT work without (I did, and ... wonder why isn't working :) )

Comment: To store it in a variable use `timer=$({ time sleep 2; } 2>&1)` and print the output using `echo "$timer"`

Answer (score 72):

Simple. The GNU `time` utility has an option for that.

But you have to ensure that you are *not* using your shell's builtin `time` command, at least the `bash` builtin does not provide that option! That's why you need to give the full path of the `time` utility:

```
/usr/bin/time -o time.txt sleep 1
```

Comment: You can also use the non-built-in without specifying the full path: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29540540/how-do-i-prevent-bash-to-use-a-builtin-command

Answer (score 57):

Wrap `time` and the command you are timing in a set of brackets.

For example, the following times `ls` and writes the result of `ls` and the results of the timing into `outfile`:

```
$ (time ls) > outfile 2>&1
```

Or, if you'd like to separate the output of the command from the captured output from `time`:

```
$ (time ls) > ls_results 2> time_results
```

Comment: It is unnecessary to introduce a subshell here.

Comment: @sampson-chen That only works because ls does not write anything to stderr right? How would you "separate" the output of 'time' from that of the command to be run if the command writes to both stdout and stderr?

Comment: @January comment could be more useful.  Using parentheses starts a new shell.  To group the output without starting a new shell, use curly braces.  `{ time ls }`

Answer (score 20):

If you care about the command's error output you can separate them like this while still using the built-in time command.

```
{ time your_command 2> command.err ; } 2> time.log
```

or

```
{ time your_command 2>1 ; } 2> time.log
```

As you see the command's errors go to a file (since `stderr` is used for `time`).

Unfortunately you can't send it to another handle (like `3>&2`) since that will not exist anymore outside the `{...}`

That said, if you can use GNU time, just do what @Tim Ludwinski said.

```
\time -o time.log command
```

Answer (score 10):

Since the output of 'time' command is error output, redirect it as standard output would be more intuitive to do further processing.

```
{ time sleep 1; } 2>&1 |  cat > time.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

```
&>out time command >/dev/null
```

in your case

```
&>out time sleep 1 >/dev/null
```

then

```
cat out
```

Comment: Elegant idea, but leads to the shell not using its built-in command. If you don't have a real `time` binary installed, `out` will contain something like `bash: time: command not found`.

Comment: Also the format for the GNU time is not the same as the bash builtin, causing problems for automatic parsing.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using GNU time instead of the bash built-in, try

```
time -o outfile command
```

(Note: GNU time formats a little differently than the bash built-in).

Comment: This, thank you. And you can use `\time -o outfile command` (with `\`) for use GNU instead of built in.

Answer (score 5):

I ended up using:

```
/usr/bin/time -ao output_file.txt -f "Operation took: %E" echo lol
```

- Where "a" is append
- Where "o" is proceeded by the file name to append to
- Where "f" is format with a printf-like syntax
- Where "%E" produces 0:00:00; hours:minutes:seconds
- I had to invoke /usr/bin/time because the bash "time" was trampling it and doesn't have the same options
- I was just trying to get output to file, not the same thing as OP

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

_onexit() {
    [[ $TMPD ]] && rm -rf "$TMPD"
}

TMPD="$(mktemp -d)"
trap _onexit EXIT

_time_2() {
    "$@" 2>&3
}

_time_1() {
    time _time_2 "$@"
}

_time() {
    declare time_label="$1"
    shift
    exec 3>&2
    _time_1 "$@" 2>"$TMPD/timing.$time_label"
    echo "time[$time_label]"
    cat "$TMPD/timing.$time_label"
}

_time a _do_something
_time b _do_another_thing
_time c _finish_up
```

This has the benefit of not spawning sub shells, and the final pipeline has it's stderr restored to the real stderr.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to touch the original process' stdout and stderr, you can redirect stderr to file descriptor 3 and back:

```
$ { time { perl -le "print 'foo'; warn 'bar';" 2>&3; }; } 3>&2 2> time.out
foo
bar at -e line 1.
$ cat time.out

real    0m0.009s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.000s
```

You could use that for a wrapper (e.g. for cronjobs) to monitor runtimes:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "[$(date)]" "$@" >> /my/runtime.log

{ time { "$@" 2>&3; }; } 3>&2 2>> /my/runtime.log
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `csh` you can use:

```
/usr/bin/time --output=outfile -p $SHELL  -c 'your command'
```

For example:

```
/usr/bin/time --output=outtime.txt -p csh -c 'cat file'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want **just** the time in a shell variable then this works:

```
var=`{ time <command> ; } 2>&1 1>/dev/null`
```