# Strange behaviour of indirection operator > in bash

Tags: linux, bash, io-redirection

I was trying to do this to dump all the output from command line to time.txt file as it is needed for my script.

```
(time echo "hi") > time.txt
```

What I observed is output of `time` command is going to terminal.

```
real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

and output of echo command is redirected to time.txt

```
$ cat time.txt
$ hi
```

Why is it so ?
I'm having hard time to understand this.
How can I redirect output of `time` command to a file ?

I'm using ubuntu14.04 in case it matters.

In [Is there a way to redirect time output to file in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356628/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-time-output-to-file-in-linux) there is one answer which redirects EVERYTHING to `time.txt`.

But in my case I just want `time.txt` to contain just the output of the `time` command, NOT the output of the `echo`.

Comment: `{ time echo "hi" ; } 2> t` redirects the output of `time` to `t`, whereas `hi` is printed in the output. Isn't this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Not very sure why this post [got reopened](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30187786/revisions).</sub>

As seen in [Is there a way to redirect time output to file in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13356654/1983854), you need to use:

```
{ time echo "hi" ; } 2> time.txt
```