# How to put Linux commands in parentheses?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, command-line

I have a question to an answer I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356628/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-time-output-to-file-in-linux). If I want to redirect the output of the `time` command with

```
{ time somecommand ; } &> file.txt
```

Why is the empty space in the beginning and the semicolon needed? And is there a difference if I just used

```
(time somecommand) &> file.txt
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out? How are you curious enough to ask the question but not have tried to answer it?!

Comment: Thanks for this helpful comment...Of course I've tried it. But it doesn't work if I ommit the space and I'd like to learn more about it. I want to understand why this is and what's the difference between the different possibillities to use parantheses. And only because I couldn't notice a difference between the two commands, doesn't mean that there isn't one.

Comment: So *mention that*. Show your working; what have you tried, what have you read, ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And is there a difference if I just used (time somecommand) &> file.txt  ?

The difference is command(s) in `( ... )` run in a subshell;it's a different process. Whereas, commands under `{...}` runs in the *same* shell. From [bash manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html):

> ```
>  (list) list is executed in a subshell environment (see COMMAND
>          EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT below).  Variable assignments and
>          builtin commands that affect the shell's environment do not
>          remain in effect after the command completes.  The return
>          status is the exit status of list.
> ```

As for the spaces in compound commands, it's required by the bash grammar:

> ```
> { list; }
>           list is simply executed in the current shell environment.
>           list must be terminated with a newline or semicolon.  This is
>           known as a group command.  The return status is the exit
>           status of list.  Note that unlike the metacharacters ( and ),
>           { and } are reserved words and must occur where a reserved
>           word is permitted to be recognized.  Since they do not cause a
>           word break, they must be separated from list by whitespace or
>           another shell metacharacter.
> ```