# Get the output of time(1) in bash

Tags: bash, time, compilation

I am using a bash to compile c++ and Java programs. 
I need to use the data that time adds, "real", "User", "Sys". 
Even though I used var=$( compile ) to get output it shows nothing.

Is there a way to get as a varialbe the outout data of time?

Edited:

I am running the bash on Java with a Proccess and reading the InputStream with a BufferReader.

Comment: Cross-site dupe: https://serverfault.com/questions/175376/redirect-output-of-time-command-in-unix-into-a-variable-in-bash

Comment: And closely related (asks about redirection to file, but underlying problem is the same): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356628/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-the-time-command-to-a-file-in-linux

Comment: and [BashFAQ/032](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the full output `time echo "hi"`, and save this to a variable:

```
stats=$({ time echo "hi"; } 2>&1)
```

or to a file:

```
{ time echo "hi"; } >mylogfile.txt 2>&1
```

The brace syntax here lets bash know what actual information you want. Because time is a reserved word in bash (like `if` or `while`), as well as a built-in, redirecting `stdout` or `stderr` without braces will not redirect the output from `time`. To do that, we need to group all the output from the command together, and then redirect it.

However, **if you only want the timing info**, we can redirect the command's information to the void `/dev/null` and keep only `time`'s output. We can save this to a variable:

```
stats=$({ time echo "hi" 1>/dev/null 2>&1; } 2>&1)
```

or to a file:

```
{ time echo "hi" 1>/dev/null 2>&1; } 2>mylogfile.txt
```

Comment: `time` is, at least in Bash, more likely a built-in, so `man time` isn't authoritative, as it refers the binary at `/usr/bin/time` or wherever it is installed; `help time` or the Bash man page would have to be consulted.

Comment: (Which has on effect on the solution of redirecting stderr.)

Comment: `help time` is super unhelpful imo. `man time` at least points out that the output is in stderr, even if it shouldn't be taken as gospel.

Comment: Helpful or not, `man time` talks about something most likely not being executed when you do `time <command>`. It's not shipped with Bash. `man bash` has more information under SHELL GRAMMAR / Pipelines, but still doesn't mention that output goes to stderr. It could be argued that writing to stderr is simply [POSIX conformant](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/time.html) and also intuitively makes sense, as otherwise the output from `time` would pollute a pipeline that's being measured.

Answer (score 1):

Time output goes to the error output, so you can use [getErrorStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getErrorStream--) in the process, and then you will get the output from time.