# How to redirect stdout and stderr for both commands, when one command is argument of the other

Tags: linux, bash, io-redirection

##### The problem

Some programs (*'called-command'*) receive as part of their parameters, another program with its own parameters (*'indirect-command'*). Such is the case of the commands `time`, `timeout`, `stdbuf`, `perf`, and many others.

**I am trying to capture stdout and stderr of the *'called'* as well as the *'indirect'* commands in independent files.**

Conceptually speaking, I want something like this, but of course, this doesn't work as I am typing it:

```bash
/usr/bin/time -p -- { \
    timeout -k 10 7 { \
        stdbuf -oL { \
            ./main >main_out.log 2>main_err.log; \
        } \
    } 2>timeout.log; \
} 2>time.log
```

In other words:

- `stderr` of the command `time` into file `time.log`
- `stderr` of the command `timeout` into file `timeout.log`
- let the `stdout` and `stderr` of the command `stdbuf` be part of `timeout`'s out/err.
- `stdout` and `stderr` of my program `main` into file `main_out.log` and `main_err.log` respectively.

##### What I have checked/tried

I am aware that `time` has the option `-o OUTPUT_FILE`, but that is a particular feature of `time`, and I would like to know a generic way in which to capture outputs/errors of commands that are parameters of other commands.

> I am suspecting that perhaps this cannot be generically done, because the *'called-command'* actually just receives a number of strings. It is up to the *'called-command'* to interpret those strings as its own options and from some point recognize the here called (*'indirect-command'*). Therefore, it is not forced to treat the characters `<` or `>` in any special manner...

- In general my internet searches land to examples related to pipes, `&&`, `||`, or blocks such as `while` loops. After trying to adapt what they present, I don't think they apply here.
- Surrounding the "child-arguments" in quotations marks (of different flavors,) fails because the "parent-command" tries to lookup the whole string as a command name. (Along the lines of `'timeout -k 10 7...' does not exist`)
- I tried parenthesis and curly brackets as suggested here [How to redirect the output of the time command to a file in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356628/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-the-time-command-to-a-file-in-linux), but after fidgeting for a good while, I still cannot make it work.
- `tee` was mentioned in the comments, but I cannot see how to use it in this case. Also, I would prefer not to pollute the results of `time` by adding new forks.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to take a look at the `tee` utility.

Comment: I am familiar with `tee`, I perhaps lack the imagination on how to use it in this case. I am comfortable with it when I am dealing with pipes and `&&`/`||` logic. But here I don't see how to use it.

Comment: You can't run a command in single quotes directly like `'command args'` but you can run `sh -c 'command args'`. Of course, the explicit shell adds a new process, which you wanted to avoid.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] including a command you will run (and that we can also run for testing purposes) with the stderr/stdout not redirected so we can see where the issues are with that.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do can be done with `tee` and `exec` working together. Try the following example:

```
/usr/bin/time -p -- { \
    exec 2>timeout.log; \
    timeout -k 10 7 { \
        exec > >(tee -a timeout.log) 2> >(tee -a timeout.log >&2); \
        stdbuf -oL { \
            exec >main_out.log 2>main_err.log; \
            ./main; \
        } \
    } \
} 2>time.log
```

Comment: I obtain the error `bash: syntax error near unexpected token \`}'` three times.

Comment: Try adding a semicolon before the second and third closing curlies. (But I'm slightly skeptical about their actual usefulness here.)

Comment: All these commands expect executable files, not arbitrary shell commands, as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this can meet your requirements :

```
/usr/bin/time -p --\
    bash -c '"$@" 2>timeout.log'                _ timeout -k 10 7 \
    bash -c '"$@"'                              _ stdbuf -oL\
    bash -c '"$@" >main_out.log 2>main_err.log' _ ./main \
    2>time.log
```

Yes, the idea  is to spawn one bash instance per "nesting-level".

I have updated `main` to `./main`, it should work now.

The underscore is a placeholder for $0 of each bash process.

Comment: Could you please tell me what is that underscore notation? When I run it I get `_: line 1: main: command not found`. It looks like your idea is to spawn one bash instance per "nesting-level", correct?