# How to capture output of several commands?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, time

I have command producing output belonging to different commands.

```
s=$(time dd if=<source> of=/dev/null bs=<number> count=<number> 2>&1)
```

`$s` will contain output only from dd command. How can I have another variable which will contain the output from `time`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3928430/469220

Comment: You can also use `/usr/bin/time` or `/bin/time` instead of the shell built-in. That's a regular command that follows the regular rules of redirection. The `bash` built-in `time` is slightly weird, as you've discovered.

Comment: @Jonathan, thank you for comment. I can use only built-in command.

Comment: See also [`bash` script write executing time in a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176611/bash-script-write-executing-time-in-a-file).

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
s=$({ time dd ... > /dev/null;} 2>&1)
```

Chepners answer gave me inspiration for the arguably better:

```
s=$(exec 2>&1; time dd ... > /dev/null)
```

`$()` is already a subshell, so no need to create an extra subshell. Putting `exec 2>&1;` before the command redirects the stdout of the entire subshell, putting it after the command would make it part of the command to `time` and hence is applied only to the command passed to `time`. Omitting the `exec` and semicolon will try to execute the system `time` binary intead of the builtin, and error out if that does not exist. Omitting just the `exec` but keeping the semicolon will not work as that would cause only newly forked processes to be redirected and the time builtin will not be a new process.

Oh and by the way, the `> /dev/null` does not dump the output of `time` itself to /dev/null because it too is part of the command that `time` executes and is not applied to time itself.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler,`s=$( exec 2>&1; time dd if=something of=/dev/null )` would be indeed a more predictable behaviour ;-)

Comment: Quietly ignore me...I mistyped what you specified.

Comment: @which, I have tried your command, 's=$(2>&1 time <some command> > /dev/null) and it returns, -sh: time: command not found. I have GNU bash, version 4.1.5.

Comment: @wich, without `exec` it doesn't work in my bash shell. I seem to remember that a lone `2>&1` redirects the output of a previous command which is not there when a fresh shell starts. So what is going to happen is a bit unpredictable and seems to differ between shell versions. However, `exec 2>&1` at the begin of a shell is well documented as "global" redirection, hence my comment. :-)

Comment: @yart indeed, it seems this syntax does not work anymore on Bash 4. Or actually it might be that without the semicolon bash is trying to call a system binary instead of the builtin, I'm not 100 sure. Anyway, adding a semicolon between the redirect and time fixes it. I updated the answer.

Comment: @thom the difference is that `2>&1` only affects newly forked processes and `exec 2>&1` effects the shell globally. In this case it's a bit tricky, without the semicolon it's calling the system `time` binary so it is a newly forked process and thus is redirected. After adding the semicolon it is actually using the builtin and thus does require the `exec`. Answer updated.

Comment: @wich: Thanks, explains a lot, without exec but with semicolon -> doesn't work. with exec with semicolon -> internal time command. without exec without semicolon -> /usr/bin/time. Indeed tricky :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hello I just find out the answer.

The link from Vlad in comments gave me direction.

I can use subshells.

My command could be specified

```
s=$((time dd if=<source> of=/dev/null bs=<number> count=<number> 2>&1 | tail -n1) 2>&1)
```

Then I can have $s variable containing all data and I can have array and get values.

Answer (score 1):

The `bash` built-in `time` is a special built-in that writes to standard error of the current shell, so you cannot simply redirect its output. Instead, you would need to run it in a subshell whose standard error has already been redirected. This causes the "real" command to *also* run in a subshell, so you can't simply assign its output to variable, as that variable will go away with the subshell. Try this:

```
s=$( exec 2>time.txt; time echo foo )
t=$(< time.txt)
```