# Pipe output from time command

Tags: bash, unix, time, grep

I have a process that I want to log how long it took. I currently view the `time` output which looks like:

```
$ time ls

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.001s
```

I want to capture the elapsed time (the "real" entry) and record it in a database (or text file, or whatever), but I don't know how to do that without also redirecting the standard error output of the command being timed, which I want to avoid.

Comment: probably relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342826/how-to-pipe-stderr-and-not-stdout

Comment: There are duplicates for this.  It is surprisingly hard.  IIRC, `(time ls) 2>time.log` will put the output of `time` into `time.log`.

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26784870/parsing-the-output-of-bashs-time-builtin (especially my answer that will show you how to format the output of `time`).

Comment: See also [Bash script — writing executing time in a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176611/bash-script-write-executing-time-in-a-file/).  It's an earlier duplicate; I don't know that it's the earliest.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Indeed it's an earlier duplicate... (I only remembered the question I answered and wasn't really aware of the older one)

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: you were just the FGITW; the one I suggest has an answer from me, which is why _I_ remember it.  The main thing is the OP has (multiple) answers and people don't spend lots of time repeating what's already available information on SO.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler as an apology, please accept my upvote on your answer `:)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the file descriptors  unmodified, so those solutions won't work. The command after time ssh's in to a server, and the 2>&1 messes up the process. the file descript redirection sends everything, not just time's output.

Comment: I might just have to get a before and after time and pipe it to calc.

Comment: `X=`date +%s`; ssh remotehost ; Y=`date +%s`; echo "$Y-$X" | calc  -p > out.calc `
works

Comment: The way your question is asked is answered exactly in the question given as a link, as my answer there also shows how to preserve stdout and stderr of the command. If you're having a specific problem with `ssh`, then please ask another question, mentioning this one (or the duplicate) and explain why it doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: gniourf_gniourf , I tried your command, it did not work for me.