# Grep time command output

Tags: linux

Using `time ls`, I have the following output:

```
$ time ls -l 
total 2
-rwx------+ 1 FRIENDS None 97 Jun 23 08:59 location.txt
-rw-r--r--+ 1 FRIENDS None 10 Jun 23 09:06 welcome
real    0m0.040s
user    0m0.000s    
sys     0m0.031s
```

Now, when I try to `grep` only the *real* value line, the actual result is:

```
$ time ls -l | grep real
real    0m0.040s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.031s
```

My question is, how to get only the real value as output? In this case, `0m0.040s`.

Comment: `time` is sending its output to stderr, not stdout, so `grep` isn't processing *any* of its output.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`time` writes its output to stderr, so you need to pipe stderr instead of stdout. But it's also important to remember that `time` is part of the syntax of bash, and it times an entire pipeline. Consequently, you need to wrap the pipeline in braces, or run it in a subshell:

```
 $ { time ls -l >/dev/null; } 2>&1 | grep real
 real   0m0.005s
```

With Bash v4.0 (probably universal on Linux distributions but still not standard on Mac OS X), you can use `|&` to pipe both `stdout` and `stderr`:

```
{ time ls -l >/dev/null; } |& grep real
```

Alternatively, you can use the `time` utility, which allows control of the output format. On my system, that utility is found in `/usr/bin/time`:

```
/usr/bin/time -f%e ls -l >/dev/null
```

`man time` for more details on the `time` utility.

Comment: `|&` does the trick for me.

Answer (score 20):

```
(time ls -l)  2>&1 > /dev/null |grep real
```

This redirects stderr (which is where time sends its output) to  the same stream as stdout, then redirects stdout to dev/null so the output of ls is not captured, then pipes what is now the output of time into the stdin of grep.

Comment: To be complete, you should add `| awk '{print $2}'` to the end, as the OP requires only the time portion.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Indeed so - but we should leave _something_ for the OP to do :-)

Answer (score 14):

If you just want to specify the output format of `time` *builtin*, you can modify the value of `TIMEFORMAT` environment variable instead of filtering it with `grep`.

In you case,

```
TIMEFORMAT=%R
time ls -l
```

would give you the "real" time only.

[Here's the link](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html) to relevant information in Bash manual (under "TIMEFORMAT").

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928430/struggling-to-parse-bash-time-command) is a similar question on SO about parsing the output of `time`.

Comment: Even better output this way.

serafina@box:~$ TIMEFORMAT=%R && time ls > /dev/null
0.001

Answer (score 3):

Look out..   bash has a built-in "time" command.  Here are some of the differences..

```
# GNU time command (can also use $TIMEFORMAT variable instead of -f)
bash> /usr/bin/time -f%e ls >/dev/null
0.00


# BASH built-in time command (can also use $TIME variable instead of -f)
bash> time -f%e ls >/dev/null
-f%e: command not found

real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Answer (score -1):

I think, it can be made a little easier:

```
time ls &> /dev/null | grep real
```