# Get both outputs from a single time command

Tags: linux, macos, bash, time

OK, this is what I'm trying to do :

- Execute a command, and time it at the same time (using `time`)
- Get its output
- Get time elapsed

**That's my code so far :**

```
for filepath in $files
do
(
output=$(time $filepath &>1)
echo ${output}
)
done
```

However, every command still outputs its time to screen, and `$output` contains the command's output.

Any ideas how to get both of them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Struggling to parse (bash) time command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928430/struggling-to-parse-bash-time-command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to catch stdin and stdout. For this, and based on the solution in [Is there a way to redirect time output to file in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356628/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-time-output-to-file-in-linux), I would say do:

```
{ time command ; } 2>&1
                   ^^^^
                   redirect stderr to stdin
```

So you for example do:

```
$ var=$({ time echo 1 ; } 2>&1 )

$ echo "$var"
1

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Comment: I think he meant to get `time` results and program output separately. If no then this answer is more correct than mine

Answer (score 2):

`time` writes its output to `stderr` or to a `<file>`, if `-o <file>` option specified (supported by both GNU and FreeBSD time). So I think you can't avoid using a (temporary) file to achieve the goal. You may use `mktemp` command to safely create a temporary file in shell.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're describing the `time` program, not `bash`'s built-in command. `command time $filepath > output.txt 2> time.txt`.