# Parsing the output of Bash's time builtin

Tags: bash, parsing, awk, command, output

I'm running a C program from a Bash script, and running it through a command called time, which outputs some time statistics for the running of the algorithm.

If I were to perform the command

```
time $ALGORITHM $VALUE $FILENAME
```

It produces the output:

```
real    0m0.435s
user    0m0.430s
sys     0m0.003s
```

The values depending on the running of the algorithm

However, what I would like to be able to do is to take the 0.435 and assign it to a variable.
I've read into awk a bit, enough to know that if I pipe the above command into awk, I should be able to grab the 0.435 and place it in a variable. But how do I do that?

Many thanks

Comment: did you want to store only `0.435` form the real line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Struggling to parse (bash) time command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928430/struggling-to-parse-bash-time-command)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You must be careful: there's the Bash builtin `time` and there's the external command `time`, usually located in `/usr/bin/time` (type `type -a time` to have all the available `time`s on your system).

If your shell is Bash, when you issue

```
time stuff
```

you're calling the builtin `time`. You can't directly catch the output of `time` without some minor trickery. This is because `time` doesn't want to interfere with possible redirections or pipes you'll perform, and that's a good thing.

To get `time` output on standard out, you need:

```
{ time stuff; } 2>&1
```

(grouping and redirection).

Now, about parsing the output: parsing the output of a command is usually a bad idea, especially when it's possible to do without. Fortunately, Bash's `time` command accepts a format string. From the manual:

> `TIMEFORMAT`
>
> The value of this parameter is used as a format string specifying how the timing information for pipelines prefixed with the time reserved word should be displayed. The `%` character introduces an escape sequence that is expanded to a time value or other information. The escape sequences and their meanings are as follows; the braces denote optional portions.
>
> `%%`
>
> ```
>    A literal `%`.
> ```
>
> `%[p][l]R`
>
> ```
>    The elapsed time in seconds.
> ```
>
> `%[p][l]U`
>
> ```
>    The number of CPU seconds spent in user mode.
> ```
>
> `%[p][l]S`
>
> ```
>    The number of CPU seconds spent in system mode.
> ```
>
> `%P`
>
> ```
>    The CPU percentage, computed as (%U + %S) / %R.
> ```
>
> The optional `p` is a digit specifying the precision, the number of fractional digits after a decimal point. A value of 0 causes no decimal point or fraction to be output. At most three places after the decimal point may be specified; values of p greater than 3 are changed to 3. If `p` is not specified, the value 3 is used.
>
> The optional `l` specifies a longer format, including minutes, of the form `MMmSS.FFs`. The value of `p` determines whether or not the fraction is included.
>
> If this variable is not set, Bash acts as if it had the value
>
> `$'\nreal\t%3lR\nuser\t%3lU\nsys\t%3lS'`
>
> If the value is null, no timing information is displayed. A trailing newline is added when the format string is displayed.

So, to fully achieve what you want:

```
var=$(TIMEFORMAT='%R'; { time $ALGORITHM $VALUE $FILENAME; } 2>&1)
```

As [@glennjackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) points out, if your command sends any messages to standard output and standard error, you must take care of that too. For that, some extra plumbing is necessary:

```
exec 3>&1 4>&2
var=$(TIMEFORMAT='%R'; { time $ALGORITHM $VALUE $FILENAME 1>&3 2>&4; } 2>&1)
exec 3>&- 4>&-
```

**Source:** [BashFAQ032](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032) on the wonderful [Greg's wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/).

Comment: @Struan, if the $ALGORITHM command emits anything to stdout, you'll need to add `1>/dev/null` **after** `2>&1`

Comment: @glennjackman On the wonderful [Greg's wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/): [How can I redirect the output of `time` to a variable or file?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032).

Comment: That's awesome. I was about to post another thread about why the output was being a bit funny, but you saved me that. Thanks!

Comment: @glennjackman you're absolutely right about `$ALGORITHM`'s output. I've added a word about it. Thanks.

Comment: If anyone's interested, I ended up using it to create a time complexity graph to analyse performance of algorithms I've been writing. 
Here's an example of it running: http://i.imgur.com/VmV7VjE.png

Again, thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below awk command which uses split function to split the input based on `digit m` or last `s`.

```
$ foo=$(awk '/^real/{split($2,a,"[0-9]m|s$"); print a[2]}' file)
$ echo "$foo"
0.435
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've tried this so far, yet it prints out the original output, not the 0.435
http://hastebin.com/ocogimesum.pl

Comment: Note `time`'s output normally goes to stderr, so you have to redirect.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this awk:

```
var=$(awk '$1=="real"{gsub(/^[0-9]+[hms]|[hms]$/, "", $2); print $2}' file)
echo "$var"
0.435
```

Comment: Thanks @fedorqui, after spending 4+ years on SO you will have more than 200k

Comment: You need special skills for such numbers, I will sit back and enjoy you gurus :) Congrats!

Comment: Note `time`'s output normally goes to stderr, so you have to redirect.