# Parse time cmdline output using awk cmdline

Tags: bash, parsing, time, awk, output

I have a program that I am timing, lets say `some_bin`. I run the time command and it produces output like so:

```
time -p some_bin --some-args=args
real 1.09
user 1.08
sys 0.00
```

I want to get just the 1.09 real time the program was in use. I'm trying to use awk in this case to pattern match the first line on `real` and then extract the time.

Everything I've tried thus far however has failed to work. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Duplictate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26784870/parsing-the-output-of-bashs-time-builtin/26785328#26785328

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`time` command's output comes after completion of your command and it is **written on stderr**. You can use it like this:

```
( time -p some_bin --some-args=args ) |& awk '/real/{print $2}'
```

You can also use:

```
( time -p some_bin --some-args=args ) 2>&1 |  awk '/real/{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Both these command would provide the real time on its own

```
/usr/bin/time -f "%e" MYCOMMAND

TIMEFORMAT='%2R'; time MYCOMMAND
```

`TIMEFORMAT` also allows you to change the precision of the time output.

#### example output

```
/usr/bin/time -f "%e" sleep 2
2.00
```

.

```
TIMEFORMAT='%2R'; time sleep 2
2.00
```