# storing the output of time in a variable

Tags: bash

I have the following command line:

```
time `while [ $i -lt 200000 ]; do i=$[$i+1]; done` | grep "real"
```

from what I know of bash this should first give me the run time of the while loop and use it as the input for the `grep` command and then the `grep` command should print out only the real time given by the `time` command but instead it prints the full output of the `time` command

so why is it not working as I would expect. also is there a better way to do this?

Comment: As an aside: Do not put the command to time in backticks. What makes time special (a shell keyword) is that it allows you to specify a command line to time _as is_  - even an _entire pipeline_. Indeed, that's the source of your problem: the `grep` command becomes part of what is being timed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bash-builtin `time` command is a bit of a special case in bash. In fact, it's classified as a keyword (try running `type time`).

It prints its output on stderr, but through some magic bash sort of "raises" that output outside of its containing pipeline, so even if you pipe stderr from the command through a pipe, it won't get through.

What you need to do is surround the `time` command in a braced block (this causes the output of `time` to become part of the block's stderr stream), redirect the block's stderr through a pipe, and then you'll have the `time` output:

```
{ time while [ $i -lt 200000 ]; do i=$[$i+1]; done; } 2>&1| grep real;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to capture stderr from `time`:

```
$ i=0; { time while [ "$i" -lt 200000 ]; do i=$[$i+1]; done; } 2>&1 | grep "real"
real    0m2.799s
```

#### Discussion

The shell keyword `time` operates on a whole pipeline and reports the timing information on stderr.  To capture that output, it is necessary to put `time` inside a group, `{...;}`, or subshell, `(...)`, and then collect the stderr from that list or subshell.

#### Documentation

`man bash` explains the pipeline syntax as follows:

```
   Pipelines
       A  pipeline  is  a  sequence  of one or more commands separated by one of the control operators | or |&.  The format for a
       pipeline is:

              [time [-p]] [ ! ] command [ [|⎪|&] command2 ... ]

   ...

   If  the  time reserved word precedes a pipeline, the elapsed as well as user and system time consumed by its execution are
   reported when the pipeline terminates.
```

Comment: @mklement0 Thank you for catching that.  I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Really, your `grep` is not a good idea. Bash has a wonderful `time` keyword and you can format its output as you wish.

In your case, I'd just do this:

```
TIMEFORMAT=$'real\t%3lR'
i=0
time while [ "$i" -lt 200000 ]; do i=$[$i+1]; done
```

See the `TIMEFORMAT` specs in [Bash Variables section](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Variables).

---

Now, your command shows antique shell techniques. In modern Bash, your `while` loop would be written as:

```
while ((i<200000)); do ((++i)); done
```

---

About the `time` keyword, you can also have a look at this question: [Parsing the output of Bash's time builtin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26784870/parsing-the-output-of-bashs-time-builtin).

Comment: Nicely done; never knew about `TIMEFORMAT`; sneak preview of the manual (sans format modifiers): `%R` is the real time elapsed, `%U` is the time spent in user mode, `%S`, the time spent in system mode. `%P` reports the CPU percentage. Format modifiers:  A number between 0 and 3 determines the decimal places, and `l` shows minutes and (fractional) seconds (instead of just seconds). Given that `%R` presumably includes time spent servicing _other_ processes, is there an easy way to get the total time spent on _just_ the bash command?