# egrep output doesn't forward all lines to file

Tags: bash, time, output

I was trying to compose a command that would monitor the stability of the script on server by curling it every couple of minutes (actual path to script was replaced):

```
while :; do date +"%T" >> monitor.txt; time curl -Is http://googel.com | egrep "HTTP|m.\." >> monitor.txt; echo ================ >> monitor.txt; sleep 30; done
```

The problem is that for some reason part of output is not forwarded to file monitor.txt. So file contains following lines:

```
$ cat monitor.txt
19:39:10
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
================
19:39:40
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
================
```

..while time details go to default output:

```
$ while :; do date +"%T" >> monitor.txt; time curl -Is http://googel.com | egrep "HTTP|m.\." >> monitor.txt; echo ================ >> monitor.txt; sleep 30; done

real    0m0.075s
user    0m0.005s
sys     0m0.003s

real    0m0.106s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.005s
```

Could you please point out, what am I missing here? Basically I would run this command in a background and check monitor.txt for results.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `time` [applies to the whole pipeline](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pipelines), not just the first command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `time` command sends its output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  Your redirection only affects `stdout`, so the `time` output ends up going
to the console.

To add to the confusion, `bash` also has a builtin `time` command, which
is a bit trickier to redirect.  If you use `/usr/bin/time` instead of
`time`, you should be able to redirect its output with the `2>&1` syntax.
Or if you prefer the bash builtin version of the command, you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26785328/153430) for a way
to redirect its output.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out Jim. Really appreciated it.
I have tried to do some research about forwarding both stderr and stdout to file, however following options (recommended here on SO) still give same result as my original command:
` &> monitor.txt` and 
` 2>&1 | tee -a monitor.txt`

So I am afraid  that I am back to the point I begun from.

Comment: @Nick, you're right...I've updated my answer with a few additional details.

Comment: Thank you very much Jim! I have just got to similar post from my side =)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356628/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-time-output-to-file-in-linux

So following syntax works like a charm:
$ while :; do date +"%T" >> monitor.txt; { time curl -Is http://googel.com | egrep "HTTP|m.\." ; } 1>>monitor.txt 2>> monitor.txt; echo ================ >> monitor.txt; sleep 30; done