# Comparing output of time command in shell to a constant

Tags: bash, shell, time

I want to measure in shell how long it takes to execute a script. I use the built in command 'time'.

For example for

```
time (sleep 5)
```

I get

```
real    0m5,003s
user    0m0,001s
sys     0m0,000s
```

Now I want to compare if the real duration (0m5,003s) is less than 10 seconds.

How can I access the real time to use it?

Comment: I cannot type a greeting haha. So Hello everyone :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing the output of Bash's time builtin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26784870/parsing-the-output-of-bashs-time-builtin)

Comment: Hi @U880D thank you for the link. I am a beginner in shell and I dont really understand how to do it. I want to save the real time from the output and use it for further applications.

Comment: No problem, we started all as beginners. The solution to your problem is given [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26785328/6771046). I would almost repeat only what is already explained in a very good way. You may start with having a look at the structure `echo $(TIMEFORMAT='%R'; { time sleep 5; } 2>&1)`.

Comment: @psad: This might help : https://serverfault.com/questions/175376/redirect-output-of-time-command-in-unix-into-a-variable-in-bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With bash, if you just need the duration in seconds, use the builtin `SECONDS` variable:

```sh
SECONDS=0
some long running process here
duration=$SECONDS

if ((duration > 10)); then
    echo "it took a long time"
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

Please see below code which will redirect into a variable and different options by which you can achieve it:
**Option 1**:

```
# !/usr/bin/bash
var=`(time (sleep 5)) 2>&1 | grep real`
```

**Output**:
real 0m5.069s

You can execute your script inside it as below :

```
# !/usr/bin/bash
var=`(time sh  ./yourscript.sh) 2>&1 | grep real`
```

**Option 2**: Get time taken by the script to execute

```
# !/usr/bin/bash
start=$(date +%s)
# Execute another script
sh  ./yourscript.sh
end=$(date +%s)
diff=$(( $end- $start))
echo "It took $diff seconds"
```

**Output** : It took 5 seconds

**Option 3**:

```
# !/usr/bin/bash
#var=$( TIMEFORMAT="%R"; { time  (sleep 5); } 2>&1 )  
var=$( TIMEFORMAT="%R"; { time  sh  ./yourscript.sh; } 2>&1 )
```

Based on good feedback of @Charles Duffy: Changed some parts and 
If targeting bash 4.3 or later, consider `printf -v start '%(%s)T' -1` as a much more efficient alternative to `start=$(date +%s)`.

Comment: Why use backticks (rather than modern command substitution syntax) anywhere at all?

Comment: BTW, re: `START`/`END`/`DIFF`, consider using lower-case variable names as recommended by the POSIX spec @ https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html (read keeping in mind that since setting a shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable, namespace conventions necessarily apply to both).

Comment: Also, if targeting bash 4.3 or later, consider `printf -v start '%(%s)T' -1` as a much more efficient alternative to `start=$(date +%s)`.

Comment: Also, `echo ${var}` has the bugs described in [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` prints something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else). `echo "$var"` has the same number of characters for more-correct output; whereas `printf '%s\n' "$var"` is longer, but [also correct even in the corner cases where even `echo "$var"` gets it wrong](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo).